# When the validator finds form errors, the form page is redisplayed at the POST url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

An item is displayed at this URL:

```
/item/10101
```

using this Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/item/{itemId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String item(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, 
    @PathVariable long itemId)
{
    model = this.fillModel(itemId);
    return "item";
}
```

The page contains a form that submits to the following method in the same controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process_form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String processForm(HttpServletRequest request,
 @ModelAttribute("foo") FooModel fooModel,
    BindingResult bindResult,
    ModelMap model)
{

    FooModelValidator validator = new FooModelValidator();
    validator.validate(FooModel, bindResult);

      if (bindResult.hasErrors())
      {
        model = this.fillModel(fooModel.getItemId());
       return "item";
      }
    return "account";
}
```

If the validator finds errors in the form, it redisplays the item but instead of displaying it at the original url:

```
/item/10101
```

it displays it at its own url:

```
/process_form
```

**Is it possible to redisplay the form at the original URL?**

```
/item/10101
```

*(I've tried getting the referrer and redirecting to it in `processForm` but then all of the model contents end up displayed as URL name/value pairs:)*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process_form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String processForm(HttpServletRequest request,
 @ModelAttribute("foo") FooModel fooModel,
    BindingResult bindResult,
    ModelMap model)
{
    String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");

    FooModelValidator validator = new FooModelValidator();
    validator.validate(FooModel, bindResult);

      if (bindResult.hasErrors())
      {
        model = this.fillModel(fooModel.getItemId());
       return "redirect:" + referrer;
      }
    return "account";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

What happens is a server-side redirect (forward), which is within the same request, and so the submitted values are preserved (and displayed in the form)

The url will change if you use a client-side redirect (`return "redirect:item";`), but in that case a new request will come and the submitted values will be lost.

But here are two options that you have:

- use the same URL in the mappings for both methods and distinguish them based on request method - `GET` for the former, `POST` for the latter. This might be confusing, so document it.
- find / implement [flash scope](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=spring%20flash%20scope&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_en___BG265&ie=UTF-8) for spring-mvc. There's nothing built-in. The flash scope means that values are preserved (in the session usually) for a submit and the subsequent redirect. This option includes the manual handling, by putting the submitted object in the session, and later retrieving & removing it

Comment: Flash scope works great. Thanks! I didn't know it was called that.